# can not use function from module in Python

Tags: import, module

I can not use function random.random from the Random module in Python.
When I`m trying to use any function from yhe module, I get the following:

```
import random
x = random.random
x
<built-in method random of Random object at 0x02452D40>
```

Comment: Can you add a python tag please? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
x = random.random
```

merely assigns the variable `x` to be the function object `random.random`. I suspect you may actually want to *call* the function, which would be

```
x = random.random()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should using `random.random()` for show to random number in terminal. in addition if you want to set the range of number you can use `randint(firts, last)`